# How to groupby/aggregation on a Apache Arrow JS table

Tags: javascript, apache-arrow

Is there any way to groupby/aggregate an ApachArrowJS table?
The official docs are very short and focus on manipulating columns, and Table doesn't seem to have any functions to aggregate data. Google sends to a page with Python code. ChatGPT is also doesn't seem to know the difference between JS and Python.